# When natural I am electric, What am I?

Tags: riddle

> I have a beach body, though I'm not alive
>   When natural I am electric
>   Nowadays, all around the world I thrive
>   I can be thin or sometimes thick
>
> I am a gatekeeper as I decide 
>   
> what passes and what gets sent back
>   Infinite reuse is one of my prides
>   
> What am I? Come on Stack!

Comment: Come on someones gotta get this one

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Are you

> glass?

I have a beach body, though I'm not alive

> Glass is made from sand, hence it's "body" is made from what beaches are made of.

When natural I am electric

> The temperature needed to create glass from sand is so high it is usually not found in nature - unless sand is struck by lightning.

Nowadays, all around the world I thrive

> Glass can be found pretty much everywhere these days, but man did not always have the technology required to produce glass.

I can be thin or sometimes thick

> Glass can be produced in various thicknesses.

I am a gatekeeper as I decide 
what passes and what gets sent back

> Glass filters light.  Colored glass can reject certain wavelengths of light.  Coated glass can act as a mirror and reflect all light.

Infinite reuse is one of my prides

> Glass can easily be melted down and reformed into another glass object.

What am I? Come on Stack!

> I'm guessing this is not a "clue" to be solved, but just a way to finish the rhyme?  Thanks to DarioOO - could be a stack of glasses.

Comment: YES! Well done on this one

Comment: On the gatekeeper one, think about mirrors... Apart from that you've got them all right

Comment: One sided mirrors?

Comment: Stack of glasses?

Answer (score 5):

When natural I am electric, What am I?

> You are a wave!

When natural I am electric

> Electric wave

Nowadays, all around the world I thrive

> In every ocean

I can be thin or sometimes thick

> Thick or thin wave

I am a gatekeeper as I decide
what passes and what gets sent back

> I can prevent things from passing me

Infinite reuse is one of my prides

> evaporate, rain, wind I always come back

Comment: Welcome to puzzling. This doesn't supply an answer to the question as it doesn't offer an explanation. I must inform you that you are also wrong, but incorrect answers will still get up-votes if they are good and offer a full explanation.

Comment: Thats better, nice idea but im afraid not

Answer (score 3):

You are

> The atmosphere

I have a beach body, though I'm not alive

> The atmosphere isn't alive, but it's color can look like a "beach body" during the afternoon sunset.

When natural I am electric

> Thunder and lightning

Nowadays, all around the world I thrive

> It exists across the planet

I can be thin or sometimes thick

> The atmosphere is thick in some places, and thin in others.

I am a gatekeeper as I decide 
what passes and what gets sent back

> It literally decides what types of radiation is allowed from the Sun.

Infinite reuse is one of my prides

> Reusable wind energy

Comment: Nice idea and good explanation but I'm afraid not

Comment: Yeah, I just saw the correct one posted right after mine own

Answer (score -1):

> An EEL. Many varieties of eels which are sea fish, long and slick, give electric shocks